# Is it possible to prevent applications from changing power management status?

Tags: imac, sleep-wake

I have several apps that behave badly on an iMac when it comes to power management on macOS (Discord and [Spotify](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Mac/Bug-Spotify-prevents-Mac-from-seeping-when-paused/m-p/4799427#M539161)). They are listed with *Preventing Sleep* set to *Yes* in Activity Monitor even though they are idle (not in a call, not playing music).

Spotify seems not to care about this issue since several years, as all support requests and bug reports go unanswered.

Since it is an iMac, I cannot close the lid so I just leave the computer and expect it to go to sleep after a while according to my power settings.

Is there a way to prevent those applications from modifying the power management settings?